# passing array initial values to a C macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have been trying to define a macro `create_array` that 
would behave such that for example

`create_array(1, {7, 2, 10, 32})` would expand to:

```
 uint8_t my_entries1 [] = 
 {7, 2, 10, 32} ;
```

or `create_array(2, {7, 2, 10, 32})` to:

```
 uint8_t my_entries2 [] = 
 {7, 2, 10, 32} ;
```

my attempt at that was the following code:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

#define create_array(the_test_nb, initial_arr_values) \
     uint8_t my_entries ## the_test_nb [] =  \
     initial_arr_values ; 

int main()
{
    create_array(1, {0x22, 0x2A, 0x2B, 0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00});
}
```

unfortunately the magic didn't happen and I got an error at compile time:

```
simonlbc@simonlbc-ThinkPad-T440s:~/workspace/CCode/os$ gcc reproducible.c 
reproducible.c: In function ‘main’:
reproducible.c:9:186: error: macro "create_array" passed 33 arguments, but takes just 2
 0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00});
                                                                                                  ^
reproducible.c:9:5: error: ‘create_array’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     create_array(1, {0x22, 0x2A, 0x2B, 0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
     ^
reproducible.c:9:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

how can I can I define my macro so that I can call it like

```
create_array(1, {0x22, 0x2A, 0x2B, ...,0x00,0x00});
```

and keep on writing less code?

Comment: Try `#define create_array(N, ...) uint8_t my_entries ## N = __VA_ARGS__`

Comment: that worked thanks!! Never had an answer so fast before, you should write that as an answer so that I give you the nice green arrow :)